# Hotkey combinations don't work if done fast

Tags: javascript, events, input, keyboard, hotkeys

I'm trying to make a hotkey for a web app, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> performs the undo function.

It seems that when I press the keys fast (as I'm used to from using desktop apps a lot), it doesn't register. The single key press registers, but it misses the combination for some reason.

From what I understand, you have to keep track of which buttons are held down via keypress events, which is what I've done below.

Try the code below. Hitting <kbd>Z</kbd> outputs `Z`. Hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> slowly outputs `CTRL + Z`. Hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> quickly outputs `Z`. When I perform the action at the same speed in say Notepad for windows, it works flawlessly almost every time.

https://codepen.io/samkeddy/pen/YQjgdZ?editors=1010#0

```
var ctrlPressed=false, altPressed=false;

window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {

    hotkey = e;
    if (e.keyCode == 17) ctrlPressed = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 18) altPressed = true;
    e.preventDefault();
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    hotkey = window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == 17) ctrlPressed = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 18) altPressed = false;

        if (e.keyCode == 90){
          if (altPressed && ctrlPressed && e.keyCode == 90) 
            addText('ALT + CTRL + Z');
          else if (ctrlPressed && e.keyCode == 90) 
            addText('CTRL + Z');
            else 
              addText('Z');
    }
});

//meaningless, just adds text to doc so you can see it
function addText(text) {
  var theDiv = document.getElementById("output");
  theDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  var content = document.createTextNode(text);
  theDiv.appendChild(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use e.ctrlKey to check if ctrl is down instead of variables, and just check for the hotkey combination on keydown, don't do anything on key up.

https://codepen.io/samkeddy/pen/gRdBpq

```
function KeyPress(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event? event : e
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) addText("CTRL + Z");
  else if (evtobj.keyCode == 90) addText("Z");
}

document.onkeydown = KeyPress;
```